# why is my spring-cloud-stream test configuration also starting up rabbitMQ listeners in another class?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-config

I'm trying to do a simple spring-cloud-stream unit test to verify the wiring between streams; basically that a handler can read from one stream and write to another. This part is working fine. The problem is that other parts of the app are being started as well; namely, a rabbitMQ listener. There is a method in another class (besides the one I'm testing) which has @RabbitListener. This is the method being called. And I do have rabbit running locally on my machine, for local dev testing. But I don't want this invoked within the test scope.

The spring-cloud-stream test docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/_testing.html) example has

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

I think it's the @SpringBootTest which is starting up the entire configuration, including the RabbitMQ listeners. I've removed the webEnvironment parameter, but that didn't make a difference.

For now, the workaround is to put spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.auto-startup: false in application.yml, but that's not something I want to continue for various reasons, one of which is that I probably want to unit test that rabbitlistener at one point, albeit in a properly-limited test context.

We're using version 2.0.1 of spring-cloud-stream and spring-cloud-stream-test-support, although this seems to be a more fundamental spring configuration issue that I don't understand how to limit the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a property placeholder in the `autoStartup` property

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.auto-startup: ${auto.start:true}
```

and then use a `@TestPropertySource` in the test case to set it to false.

Comment: Thanks; So how would I turn it on again, in another test where I want it on? Is that with @Value?

Comment: Omit the property from the `@TestPropertySource` in that class (or set it to true); or you can `@Autowired` the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` and call `registry.getListenerContainer(id).start()` from the test, where `id` is the `id` property on the `@RabbitListener`.